# CSS modal with one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have modal window with pure CSS. I use for this 2 divs.

Question: How can I refactor this to **use ONE div** instead?

**Wanted usage:**

```
<div class="modal">
    some text

    <a href="">x</a>
</div>
```

**Current code:**

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uogoxj8d/

```css
.modal:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal-content a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    
    <div class="modal-content">
        some text
      
        <a href="">x</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible.. :/

Comment: I'm struggling to see what you are trying to do here.

Comment: He is trying to make the alert box with one div, instead of two

Comment: I'm struggling to see the purpose, but I'm not sure it's "impossible." Possibly not very performant and a headache to make cross-browser compatible. If I had the time I'd give it at shot, but alas, it's Halloween. One thing you might consider is amending your current HTML. Changing your anchor to a button, setting its tabindex to whatever you need, and toggling aria attributes on your modal. All helps for people using assistive devices.

Comment: @ChaseRies using :before or :after, it is impossible. The only way to get the pseudo element behind the model-content div, is to give it a -1 z-index, which puts it behind all other elements.

Comment: @ImagineStudios Is it not possible to give the parent element a z-index of 2 and the pseudoelement a z-index of 1? I'm a little hazy here.

Comment: @ChaseRies You would think it works like that, but no it doesnt :(

Comment: @ChaseRies http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/uogoxj8d/11/

Comment: Why does this need to be a single element? By taking that route you will likely lead yourself down a path of poorer performance, or inhibited accessibility.

Comment: Dear CSS: stop not making sense. Love, me.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, I get it. Simply use a giant box-shadow. Would that do?

```css
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0 0 0 9999px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
    
    <div class="modal-content">
        some text
        <a href="">close</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think of using box-shadow! Great answer!

Comment: This is nice, but I need to **DISABLE content behind modal**, so user need to interact with it to continue on browsing.

Comment: Giant semi-opaque border calculated with JS?

Comment: @ChaseRies That works with `overflow:hidden`on the body - http://jsfiddle.net/uogoxj8d/12/

Comment: Or you could use a pseudo element on the `modal-content` element itself and use overflow in the same way. That one has some `z-index` issues but nothing that can't overcome.